# ServiceBusAdministrationClient poor performance

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

When I use the `ServiceBusAdministrationClient` methods like `GetQueueAsync` and `GetSubscriptionAsync`, I am finding that the underlying requests can have very long response times, in a lot of cases longer than 2 seconds.

My service is running in an AKS cluster in the same region as the Service Bus namespace. The Service Bus namespace is on the Premium pricing tier and has 4 messaging units.

I am using these methods to determine whether there are active messages on queues/subscriptions before I try to receive a message. I understand this is not the normal approach to receiving messages, however, I am working around other constraints that are outside of my control.

Is the performance of ServiceBusAdministrationClient not guaranteed? What range of response times should I be expecting?

Comment: Is your AKS cluster in the same region as the ASB namespace? Also, `ServiceBusAdministrationClient` is HTTP-based. You might one to check if HTTP traffic outside of cluster has any issues or not to rule that option out.

Comment: Yes, the cluster is in the same region. There is other HTTP traffic that has no issues.

Comment: By default, ASB uses TCP with an established link to transfer data. Administrative client is not, it's always HTTP. A general recommendation is to avoid frequent use of the administrative client at runtime for things such as entity management because it's not supposed to have very performant. An alternative could be using `ServiceBusReceiver` to peek and receive, to avoid the use of `ServiceBusAdministrationClient`.

Comment: Is that a general recommendation from you or from Microsoft? If it's the latter, could you please send me a link? I am using `ServiceBusReceiver` to peek and receive messages. The problem is that my service monitors 20 queues and can only be allowed to receive 10 messages concurrently due to constraints in downstream services. So I want the service to have a view of the message counts in each queue so that it can prioritise the queues to receive from.

Comment: I'll give the official Microsoft version of exactly what Sean said, for the reasons that he mentioned.

Comment: @JesseSquire it would have been useful to me if this was mentioned in documentation anywhere.

Comment: Thank you for that feedback.  I've added a note to the docs: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/pull/39717